# finding parent div height and adding height to child for IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having a little difficulty with changing an elements height. When there's no flexbox available the html tag has the class no-flexbox. The code below is suposed to take the parent divs height and add it to the child. This would force equal heights in IE9. Can anyone see what's the wrong with this bit of code. I've probably done something stupid and obvious, but I can't see it.

```
   var iconGroupHeight = $('.icon-block-group-wrapper').height;

if ($('html').hasClass("no-flexbox")){
$('.icon-block').css('height', iconGroupHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this 
1st

```
.height()  or outerHeight();  dont forget ()  // it will return integer
```

2nd

```
if ($('html').hasClass("no-flexbox")){
   $('.icon-block').css('height', iconGroupHeight+'px'); // add px
 }
```

Comment: ah man! can't believe I didn't add ( ) to the height function. Thanks Mohamed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have it wrapped in a document ready so jQuery can get the rendered element's height. Also, Try the `.outerHeight` method.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var iconGroupHeight = $('.icon-block-group-wrapper').outerHeight();

  if ($('html').hasClass("no-flexbox")){
   $('.icon-block').css('height', iconGroupHeight);
  }

});
```